# Scope of variable questions in AS3

Tags: scope

```
        // content loaders
        if (_contentLoaders != null)
        {
            // iterate through all the content loaders then dispose it
            for (var i:int = 0; i < _contentLoaders.length; i++)
            {
                _contentLoaders[i].dispose();

            }
            _contentLoaders.splice(0, _contentLoaders.length);
            _contentLoaders = null;
        }

        // text content loaders
        if (_textContentLoaders != null)
        {
            // iterate through all the text content loaders then dispose it
            for (var i:int = 0; i < _textContentLoaders.length; i++)
            {
                _textContentLoaders[i].dispose();
            }
            _textContentLoaders.splice(0, _textContentLoaders.length);
            _textContentLoaders = null;
        }
```

Hello guys, I have come across many times about this problem (in fact it should not be a problem, if I understand correctly it should be a design of syntax to be like that way).

From the code above, you see 2 block of for-loop in which you see I declare variable i for each block. I run this code with FlashDevelop set up with Flash v.10.2. It prompts me error saying that **"Duplicate variable definition"**.

I could solve this problem by declare variable i outside these 2 for-loop block, and reuse i for both of them. But for myself, this is not so clean of code.
My question is

> "Is this an intention of actionscript
>   3 to be like that way ? by limitting
>   variable scope this way. Or can it be
>   modified can tune up with some option
>   to the compiler or say interpreter as
>   in this case ?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of `i` to `j` in the second loop or declare `i` outside of the for loops and all your problems will be resolved.

The issue is that once you declare `i` the first time, it is existing in the scope of the function block, so when you try to redeclare it further down in the block you are getting the error.

I personally don't see anything wrong with declaring `i` outside of the loops by the way.

This is a scope issue in AS3, and you will most likely find it in many other OOP languages as well.

Comment: That would be an idea as well, but this will increase the number of index variable to handle unnecessary.

Comment: You can't redeclare a variable with the same name, as the original will exist for the length of the function block. The only option is to declare it once and reuse it, or change the name of the second variable.

Comment: I would like it to be locally for each of loop-block.

Comment: So this means that this is the way as3 designed to be right Chris ?

Comment: It will only be localised if it is within the curly braces of the for loop. A decleration in the header of the for loop will create the variable in the scope of the function block, hence the "Duplicate Variable Definition" error.

Comment: This is the way that Object Orientated Programming is designed to be Haxpor. I'm not aware of any languages that do it otherwise, but then again I don't use every language available. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see this capability can be done via C# or other languages.
I believe I must accept this, thx for fast input Chris !

Comment: No probs! It's interesting to find out the nuances of different languages, I my self use C# but have not ever attempted what you are trying to do. I'll be interested to see for myself! Thanks.